# Weird issue with hiding checkboxes on mobile

Tags: javascript, html

So I've been working on a back-end interface for where I'm interning, and everything's been going smoothly mainly. I made a page where you insert a customer. there's a checkbox to add shipping information, and the fields are hidden, and only shown when the checkbox is ticked. it is also required when its showing. i did the same thing for a Tax Exempt check box, where it hides a field to enter a tax id, and is only required when its checked and showing, otherwise, it isn't required. both of these features work great on pc, and theyre coded exactly the same. However; when i go to try it on mobile, the shipping checkbox works, and drops down the fields to enter the info. Yet, the tax exempt box doesnt show the field to enter the Tax ID.

Shipping html:

```
                    <div id="changeShipInputs">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input id="Sstreet" name="Sstreet" type="text" maxlength="150" placeholder="Street Name (required)" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input id="Scity" name="Scity" type="text" maxlength="35" placeholder="City (required)" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input id="Sstate" name="Sstate" type="text" maxlength="35" placeholder="State (required)" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="hidden-lg hidden-md">&nbsp;</div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <input id="Szipcode" name="Szipcode" type="text" maxlength="15" placeholder="Zip (required)" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Tax html:

```
                    <div id="changeTaxInputs">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <input id="taxID" name="taxID" type="text" maxlength="15" placeholder="Tax ID: (required)" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                          <hr>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="comment">Notes:</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" maxlength="255" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <br>
                        </div>
```

Javascript:

```
var form = $('#myForm'),
checkbox = $('#changeShip'),
chShipBlock = $('#changeShipInputs');

chShipBlock.hide();

checkbox.on('click', function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      chShipBlock.show();
      chShipBlock.find('input').attr('required', true);
    } else {
      chShipBlock.hide();
      chShipBlock.find('input').attr('required', false);
    }
});

var form = $('#myForm'),
checkbox = $('#changeTax'),
chTaxBlock = $('#changeTaxInputs');

chTaxBlock.hide();

checkbox.on('click', function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      chTaxBlock.show();
      chTaxBlock.find('input').attr('required', true);
    } else {
      chTaxBlock.hide();
      chTaxBlock.find('input').attr('required', false);
    }
});
```

The first script is the shipping, the second is the tax.

can anyone tell me why JUST THE TAX BOX wont work on mobile, yet the shipping box works fine on mobile. They both work great on desktop.

Comment: Are you sure its not showing? you have there col-md-3 so on the mobile it will be 100% width so maybe it jumps to some other place and/or is covered by some other element.

Comment: I tried to set it to a md-12, and it made it the whole width, and it still worked on desktop. Still no luck on mobile though. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: could i get an upvote? i'd really like to know what the issue is here

Comment: Could you add it to jsFiddle so the same thing will happen? Maybe than i will be able to help.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/am54odsn/1/
It works fine there too, mobile is the only issue.

Comment: I just enter this jsfiddle on my mobile and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's working on JSFiddle correctly, my guess is that maybe a containing div or element is not closed correctly.  Compare the containers of the `changeShipInputs` and `changeTaxInputs` closely and report back.